# Why executing "cmd /k" after connecting in a ssh server using putty makes the keyboard stop working?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, putty, cmd.exe

I am using FreeSSHd in a Windows Server 2003 x64 and putty to connect to that ssh server from a Windows 7 x64 machine.

In the "Remote Command" of the putty interface I put `cm /k "cd c:\"`.

Everything goes fine, it connects into the server and executes the cmd, jumping into the desired directory. Th problem is that I can't type anything! The keyboard just doesn't work once putty connects and executes the command!

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The shell is likely waiting for the `cmd.exe` to complete.  The `/k` option makes the command shell to stay open after the command passed on the command line completes.  The `FreeSSHd` process spawns the `cmd.exe` process and is likely waiting for it to complete before continuing.